# How to get all classes that "participate" in a given object?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a java object, an instance of class `Object` - that's all I know about it. Now I need to create a list of `Class`-es that took participation in its creation, including its own class, all parent classes, all classes of its properties and methods. For example:

```
List obj = new ArrayList();
obj.add(new Integer(4));
obj.add(new Foo());
System.out.println(allRelatedClasses(obj));
```

Should output something like this:

```
Object, List, Collection, Iterable, Serializable, Cloneable, RandomAccess, 
ArrayList, Integer, Foo
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library can handle quite a bit of that.

In terms of "what took part in its creation", you'll need to pull that out of the bytecode. There are several libraries that can help with this, like ASM and BCEL. If you just need *all* dependencies, [DepFind](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) might be enough.

If you need to limit yourself to what you said, "what's involved in its creation", then you'd only want the classes involved in the ctor and methods the ctor calls.

If a class uses any reflection, however, all bets are off--those types of dependencies are difficult to track down, and it's difficult/impossible to identify what's *actually* used.

Comment: ASM or BCEL can help to get links to `Integer` and `Foo` in the example above?

Comment: @yegor256 Yes; you'd interrogate methods to pull out all the fully-qualified classnames used. That said, it's not clear to me if you'd need to do this manually or if DepFind or similar does it already.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it using reflection. `obj.getClass()` returns your own class, `obj.getClass().getParent()` returns its parent. Then you can call `getParent()` in loop until you arrive to `Object`.

The same is with interfaces, fields, methods, annotations. Just do not forget that you should call `getDeclaredMethods()` and `getDeclaredFields()` to get all methods and fields including private. And you have to call `setAccessible(true)` to deal with private members.

1 hour of work and you are done. Go! Good luck.

Comment: Reflection won't give me `Integer` and `Foo` in the example above, since it works with static bytecode structures, and I need to find out links to run-time objects as well